# Where can I post a suggestion for the developers of Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, meta

I noticed something about the Stack Overflow site that could be fixed (I just ran into this issue on a project of my own and found a nice solution). Where is the appropriate place to make that suggestion?

Comment: This is the appropriate place to post it. Tag your question `feature-request` if you are suggesting added functionality, or `bug` if you spot something broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right here on Meta. Just tag the question with the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag, and see what the community and devs think of it.

Comment: Wow, that's strange... I just went back to the site to try to reproduce the problem and couldn't. Oh well, never mind! :)

Comment: @JasonGaluten: :).

Comment: These SO guys are so freaking good that just "thinking" about a [feature-request] gets things done.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell: agreed! :).